# How can use built version of web component generated by Stencil js in Vue 3 +Vite?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, web-component, stenciljs

I want to build a custom web component by Stenciljs and use it in Vue3. The following repo contains the source code of web-component.   [github-source-code](https://github.com/amirtbi/stencil-web-component).

For this purpose, I run the command 'npm run build'. It generates dist and www folders. Which of them must be used in a Vue3 app?. And what is the best practice for this apporach?

Comment: https://stenciljs.com/docs/vue is the guide for using Stencil + Vue. It's been almost completely rewritten and just pushed to the site within the last few hours